# What kind of DC motor should I get for raising my blinds?

Tags: dc-motor, components, h-bridge

I have large blinds that cover sliding glass doors in my condo. Unfortunately, the draw string to raise / lower them pops out regularly. I've decided I want to automate the raising / lowering with a RPi webapp.

I have all the software working (basically just a webapp to enable / disable 2 GPIO pins), but I need to figure out which motor I should get. Here's what I've measured so far:

The draw string is a 19.5ft loop that goes through a pulley (picture here https://i.stack.imgur.com/3X4HL.jpg). It takes 1 full rotation of the entire draw string to raise / lower the blinds. The pulley is 1" diameter, and I don't want it to take more than 30s to raise / lower the blinds fully. Therefore, I determined I need 
\$\frac{19.5*12}{2\pi*.5} = 75\$ rotations and therefore a \$150\$RPM motor.

Here's where the measurements get a bit shoddy. I took a luggage scale and wrapped the pulley around it to measure the amount of tensile force in the string. It came back as \$10\$lbs. Using \$.5\$" radius, I determined that I need \$10*.5*16=80\$oz-in torque.

So that leaves me with a DC motor capable of exerting \$80\$oz-in torque at \$150\$RPM, and that's about as far as I've gotten. I know I'll also likely need an H-Bridge and of course a power supply (I assume a cheap wall wart should suffice for this). I am going to 3D print the junction between the motor and the gear/pulley thing, but that's a question for another day. So far, I've been able to narrow it down quite a bit, but there are still seemingly endless options for DC motors (BLDC vs brushed, steppers, modded servos, I saw some motors used for pumps in cars). At this point I'm trying to figure out the most suitable type of motor for my application. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Rob, shopping questions aren't allowed. See the Help Center. Your question, however, shows good engineering approach to the problem. Remove the second last sentence and ask a specific design question. Search for 12 V DC motors, have a look at the datasheets and post an excerpt if you need clarification.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've adjusted my question. Thanks!

Comment: Just in time! Go for a simple brushed DC motor - a bigger version of what you find in toys. Control (and understanding) is very simple and there's a nearly proportional relationship between current and torque. Tip: cars are full of 12 V motors with gearboxes: wipers, window winders, seat adjusters ... and they're 12 V so easy to control.

Comment: Thanks @transistor! I was also looking at stepper motors. As a software engineer that seems like the easier solution, because I simply need to send pulses and they seem to need very little supporting circuitry. I also like that I can get precise (and relatively accurate) feedback on the position. That would let me make accurate presets. Are there any drawbacks to that approach?

Comment: Stepper control is simple enough but more complex than a simple DC motor which is just on/off. Steppers normally _don't_ have feedback. You step the motor the required number of pulses and hope it doesn't stall.